# how to get $.getJSON callback to work while getting data from an api returning json instead of jsonp data

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

Am trying to get the $.getJSON call back to work for an api that is returning json instead of jsonp data. How can alter this to work.

```
$.getJSON("http://url&callback=?", function(response){ alert("hi");  });
```

Comment: alert(response) doesn't return anything.

Comment: Is it a public API? Could you show us the real url?

Comment: Remove the `callback=?` parameter from your URL. As far as I know that is only needed when you want to auto-invoke a generated callback function for JSONP. In this case you are passing in the callback function, so there's no need to generate anything.

Comment: It is difficult to give the best answer without understanding the API being used. If the API being used only supports JSONP, which would be odd, use JSONP.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, I haven't been able to get Ajax requests to work **without** callback parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Recently i worked on similar kind of issue to get the twitter count of URL using twitter API Call which generates JSON response.

Look below snippet for reference

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var url = "http://www.google.com/"; //test url 
     $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                });
});
</script>
```

I hope it will be useful for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is not a data type. If you would like to learn more about JSONP please read this SO post called ["What is JSONP all about?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/2067584#comment63666090_2067584)

You can actually use `$.ajax` or `$.get` (or any jQuery ajax methods for that matter) when making ajax requests on an OS/400 but if you are calling RPGLE PGMs from a different port than the actual HTTP SERVER/Domain then you must provide the `?callback=?` method which let's the javascript engine know its JSONP (I believe). JSONP is actually a javascript function/wrapper which allows the data to be passed to the client without any reservations. If you are using an API such as twitter where you are performing cross-domain call its better that you know the provider is SECURE.

I was getting a 500 Internal Server Error by performing a GET when actually doing a POST so I investigated the proper way to make Ajax requests.